# How to extract json data returned by php and display it in a list

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, forms

I have a simple jquery ajax form submission. On submission my php script echo's json_decode($result)

This is my ajax script

```
<script>
            $("#ajaxquery").live( "submit" , function(){
            // Intercept the form submission
            var formdata = $(this).serialize(); // Serialize all form data

            // Post data to your PHP processing script
            $.get( "getdata.php", formdata, function( data ) {
                // Act upon the data returned, setting it to #success <div>
                $("#success").html ( data );
            });

            return false; // Prevent the form from actually submitting
        });
    </script>
```

The problem is that the data is being displayed in json format.

Currently my output is like :

```
[{"id":4,"comments":1,"likes":15,"books":3,"name":"steve"}]
```

How can I display the data in a list :-

```
<ul>
    <li>id</li>
    <li>name</li>
<ul>
```

or is there a way to get these values in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need json_decode()

See http://nitschinger.at/Handling-JSON-like-a-boss-in-PHP 
and http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php

Comment: hi, but how do i pass this data "$("#success").html ( data )" to php. I guess (data) contains all the information

Answer (score 0):

Your success method can looks like this. data which is attribute of that method should be already an appropriate json object

```
success : function(data) {
            if (data[0].status === 'DONE') {
                console.log('Done');
            } else if (data[0].status === 'IN_PROGRESS') {
                console.log('In progress');
            } 
        }
```